# Docker compose: mysql port 3306 is already used, container port uses host port?

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, port

I already have a Mysql running on host at port 3306.

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    container_name: db_mysql
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - "3309:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
```

The container msyql port 3306 is mapped to host port 3309. But error:

> docker ps -a

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
```

> docker-compose up

```
Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Address already in use
[ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
```

Is container mysql port 3306 still using the host port 3306?

> docker ps -a

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                     PORTS     NAMES
103f1e16c782   mysql     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 minutes ago   Exited (1) 3 minutes ago             db_mysql
```

If the ports are commented out, same error.

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    container_name: db_mysql
    image: mysql
    #ports:
      #- "3309:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
```

### UPDATE

After stopping the Mysql on host, it worked. This means that the Docker container (mysql) uses the host port 3306?

Comment: That looks like it should be okay.  I think that's the MySQL error and not the Docker error, so it's the sort of thing you might get if you used `docker exec` to start a second database in the same container.  Is this your whole setup?

Comment: Updated. no containers are running before docker-compose up. thanks.

Comment: After stopping the Mysql on host, it worked. Does the docker container use the host port 3306?

Answer (score 0):

Docker compose run command does not create any of the ports specified in the service configuration. This prevents port collisions with already-open ports. If you do want the service’s ports to be created and mapped to the host, specify the --service-ports

`$docker compose run --service-ports SERVICE [COMMAND] [ARGS...]`

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_run/

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to guess that the default bridge network is mapping directly to the same network that the local mysql server is using.   Thus you have a port conflict when starting the container.  Add a docker network and use that.

You can get a list of the networks using `docker network ls`

You can then explore the settings of each docker network using `docker network inspect <name>` where name is one of the network names you get from the ls command.  There are a number of built-in networks like bridge.  When you don't specify a network, bridge is what will be used (assuming there is no other local configuration made to have changed this).

Specify a network for use in your docker-compose orchestration explicitly, which will create a network for use.  Frequently you will want more than one network for orchestration of multiple containers, as in the scenario where you have some application servers, a reverse proxy and a backend database like mysql.

```
version: "3"
networks: 
  dbnet:
    external: false
services:
  db:
    container_name: db_mysql
    image: mysql
    networks:
      - dbnet
    ports:
      - 3309:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
```

Comment: Compose creates a network named `default` automatically; you should not usually need to manually create networks.  Unless you explicitly disable Docker networking with `network_mode: host`, containers have isolated networks, and it should work for both a container and the host to run a MySQL server on port 3306 (mapped `ports:` could conflict, but that would be the first port 3309 here).  Also see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.

Comment: The evidence provided is that with no containers running, there's a conflict with a local mysql server running on the workstation and listening on port 3306.  It doesn't matter one bit whether by default a network is created, and was in no way different than what i stated.  If using docker-compose it uses the default bridge network, if using `docker compose` it uses a default network named something like project_default.  Both are bridge networks.  Either way, it's irrelevant to state what "usually" happens,  as that did not help, because that is not working for them.